# Get true for every match from an array of objects compare to an enum

Tags: typescript

I want to get how many matches/true based on values of all objects in an array, compared to an enums value. I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
  const jobs =  [{
    description,
    title,
    }...
    ]
```

I also have an enum:

```
enum jobFailureStatus {
value1,
value2,
...
}
```

I want to compare the "description" to any of the enums value and get an array of true/false. I have tried:

```
const found = this.jobs?.some((item) => item.description?.includes(Object.values(jobFailureStatus)))
```

I get the following type mismatch error:

```
Argument of type '(string | jobFailureStatus)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string
```

How can I "cast" the above function in such a way there is no type mismatch?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NBe3Dw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBFQITiCGhmACiqwYiAWkAAao4KAxpO5QABeUAAIgAEjBoBhwPAyNF%20cVKYJ4O4AqLmAAKOkMpnuNmUTnuACUwUUspoACt4LJeaAANqKADeihKJW4%20lg%20VAAHIAGIMTEARjdvHtDs47EQroAzIoAL4Bu0OuHO11up2CWAAJn9gZKwdDoAArFGY5n4ynE17MemA3Hs%20GC4oALoAbmCKJDoFN0jL0HxJFQeOEsYdnZ9lcH3ugqajwSNoAJUVQBXG8HlHk4lrrFvbggCiAYBGVxt5AD5QAB5aTGyCwVABHQMLv6fdmzvd4i91DsQS6gD8AQysC7yb7gEyawLqupNrKy6KvAKqztA87geSYA4M0HhkF4iASs4wLsDQXxuGYzDsAwzCQPw-7qIknLwHoIhePy9KMsygj8kk2L8uADioG6wgAHKQBI-JBCoJ5fGQ7yCGRWiQEcvZkAorjSHgM6QJhOjDFg%20goAgiDQsIlz4RIErRCIBgcNiCxMKwHA8EEJRAA)

```
const results: boolean[] = jobs.map(j => Object.values(jobFailureStatus)?.includes(j.description));
```